# Capture original payload through serde

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I wonder whether there's a way to preserve the original String using serde_json? Consider this example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub raw: String,
    pub id: u64,
    pub login: String,
}
```

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "login": "johndoe"
}
```

My structure would end up containing such values:

```rust
User {
    raw: String::from(r#"{"id": 123,"login": "johndoe"}"#),
    id: 1,
    login: String::from("johndoe")
}
```

Currently, I'm doing that by deserializing into [Value](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html), then deserializing this value into the `User` structure and assigning Value to the `raw` field, but that doesn't seem right, perhaps there's a better way to do so?

Comment: Not a complete solution, but deserialize as `RawValue` first (https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.67/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html), then deserialize `User` from `RawValue`, lastly put the `RawValue` into the `User`. You will need to implement some part without the derive.

Comment: two structure then simply clone it ? or use a lifetime to avoid clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses the [`RawValue`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.67/serde_json/value/struct.RawValue.html) type from `serde_json` to first get the original input string. Then a new `Deserializer` is created from that String to deserialize the `User` type.

This solution can work with readers, by using `Box<serde_json::value::RawValue>` as an intermediary type and it can also work with struct which borrow from the input, by using `&'de serde_json::value::RawValue` as the intermediary. You can test it in the solution by (un-)commenting the `borrow` field.

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Debug, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(remote = "Self")]
struct User<'a> {
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub raw: String,
    pub id: u64,
    pub login: String,
    // Test for borrowing input data
    // pub borrow: &'a str,
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub ignored: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl serde::Serialize for User<'_> {
    fn serialize<S: serde::Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        Self::serialize(self, serializer)
    }
}

impl<'a, 'de> serde::Deserialize<'de> for User<'a>
where
    'de: 'a,
{
    fn deserialize<D: serde::Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        use serde::de::Error;

        // Deserializing a `&'a RawValue` would also work here
        // but then you loose support for deserializing from readers
        let raw: Box<serde_json::value::RawValue> = Box::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        // Use this line instead if you have a struct which borrows from the input
        // let raw = <&'de serde_json::value::RawValue>::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        let mut raw_value_deserializer = serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(raw.get());
        let mut user =
            User::deserialize(&mut raw_value_deserializer).map_err(|err| D::Error::custom(err))?;
        user.raw = raw.get().to_string();
        Ok(user)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Test serialization
    let u = User {
        raw: String::new(),
        id: 456,
        login: "USERNAME".to_string(),
        // Test for borrowing input data
        // borrow: "foobar",
        ignored: PhantomData,
    };
    let json = serde_json::to_string(&u).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);

    // Test deserialization
    let u2: User = serde_json::from_str(&json).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", u2);
}
```

[Test on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89540f1aeb1950b07e41a11fb5609ae3).